# Can't deploy firebase Functions, Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and I was trying to do my firebase functions to be serverless. I had go through some tutorial and documentation but nothing work for me . On emulator my app works fine.
Is this something related to blaze plan? because currently I am on spark plan.

```
$ firebase deploy
```

=== Deploying to 'clone-1aab8'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

C:\Users\mycom\amazon-clone\functions\index.js
17:40  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\mycom\amazon-clone\functions" run lint ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\Users\mycom.nvm\versions\node\v16.13.1\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\mycom.nvm\versions\node\v16.13.1\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\mycom.nvm\versions\node\v16.13.1\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\mycom.nvm\versions\node\v16.13.1\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) {
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\mycom\amazon-clone\functions" run lint',
path: 'npm --prefix "C:\Users\mycom\amazon-clone\functions" run lint',
spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Firebase.json

```
{
"hosting": {
  "public": "build/",
  "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
  "rewrites": [
   {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
   }
 ]
},
"functions": {
  "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
  "source": "functions"
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to change the `predeploy` to this: `"predeploy": [
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
]`

Comment: Yes i have done that , but this didn't work for me. And I have read somewhere about removing lint but that gives me an error "currently you are on spark plan , switch on blaze plan".